# Merging and sorting two pandas data frames containing differently arranged identical content and distinct associated values

Tags: pandas

Pandas newbie here.
I have created two data frames:

df1

```
Genus-name  Domain-hit-counts
Bacillus    2228
Paenibacillus   467
Mycobacterium   415
... ...
Microbulbifer   1
Methylocella    1
Oceanobacillus  1
```

df2

```
    Num-of-genomes  Genus-name
0   221 Mycobacterium
1   193 Bacillus
2   70  Yersinia
... ...
207 1   Actinomadura
208 1   Acidothermus
209 1   Acaryochloris
```

The *Genus-name* column content is identical but ordered differently in the data frames.
I want to create a third DataFrame which contains the contents of all three data frames sorted according to the descending order of *Domain-hit-counts*, then *Num-of-genomes*. The output should look as follows:

df3

```
Genus-name  Domain-hit-counts   Num-of-genomes
Bacillus    2228    193
Paenibacillus   467 40
Mycobacterium   415 221
... ...
Microbulbifer   1   1
Methylocella    1   1
Oceanobacillus  1   1
```

How do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on="Genus-name")
df3.sort_values(by=["Domain-hit-counts", "Num-of-genomes"], ascending=[False, False], inplace=True)
df3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'.

Comment: Removing the ignore_index option gives the desired output though.

Comment: Strange..what pandas version did you used? From the doc ignore_index has been added since 1.0.0. Anyway I accepted your edit suggestion because it is more readable like this, thanks.

Comment: I am using Pandas version 0.25.1. Maybe that is the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering, I was able to achieve the desired output.
My code might be quite clunky, so pardon the noob inefficiencies.

```
# merge df1 and df2 by using the 'Genus-name' column
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = "Genus-name")

# sort by columns in the declared order of priority
df3.groupby(['Domain-hit-counts', 'Num-of-genomes', 'Genus-name'])

# reorder columns
cols = ['Genus-name', 'Domain-hit-counts', 'Num-of-genomes']
df3 = df3[cols]

# reset index
df3.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True) 

# display data frame
df3
```

Feel free to suggest any improvements in the code. :)